# приставил ссылку на ютуб, как свернуть div или svg как в примере?

Tags: javascript

пример сделан на канвасе, мне нужно сделать кодом, пробовал svg через path свернуть, но не получается, получается если добавить свойство stroke-width="1" но не то, код прикрепил, там див и отдельно svg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEUK9zze0qM

```
body {
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
  width: 100%;
  background: #424242;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.circle {
  background:#F88D0E;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius: 200px 0px 0px 0px;

}

<div class="circle">
  
</div>
<div class="svg">
  <svg width="109" height="110" viewBox="0 0 109 110" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path  d="M109 1.52588e-05C46.606 11.4 10.9393 45.4 -3.25351e-06 110L54.5 110L109 110L109 1.52588e-05Z" fill="#F88D0E"/>
</svg>

</div>
```